# Mucking hand face up

Tags: rules, reading-hands

Need some help here please
heres the scenerio Seat 4 and seat 5 are all in..2 pair on board. Seat 5 says to seat 4 you win you have the ace and shows his hand but does NOT table the hand.He then throws the card to the muck actually hitting the muck with one and the other is next to the muck.I immediately fold the hand and award the pot. As he was throwing his hand toward the muck he was half out of his seat. It was clear he thought he lost and intended to muck although he mucked face up. He left the room them came back a few minutes later saying he won the hand with pocket 10s..Should I have stopped him,should I have read the hand

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether he thought he actually mucked his hand, misread his hand, or believed he was beaten. If **both** his cards were **face-up** after he threw them (whether that was toward the muck or not), that is a showdown and his hand is alive. Your job as a dealer is to read his hand and declare the winner accordingly. That's the beauty of a "misread". players might throw their cards face-up saying: "nice hand, I only got ace high", it's the dealer's job to find out whether the player actually hit a billy buster straight on the river without being aware of it.

Having said that, it's ok to call "throwing the cards face-up toward the muck" a "bad etiquette", but not a dead hand.

Answer (score -1):

WSOP rules state that "once all players are all in and action is complete, all hands must be turned face up". All in players are generally required to show their hand to prevent collusion.

The dealer should have protected the muck and required both players to table their hands.

Comment: There's no indication that this is a tournament. This rule doesn't apply to cash games in most rooms. There's also no indication that any of these players were all in, so it wouldn't apply even in a tournament.

Comment: To your second point, the first sentence reads "seat 4 and seat 5 are all in". So both players were clearly all in. But citing tournament rules was incorrect on my part. That said, most cash games would require the dealer in this situation to protect the muck and read the hand, determining the winner.

Comment: Oh, that's true.  Good point.  I'm not sure how I missed that.